# How to tell Emma which test classes to use in a maven project

Tags: maven, code-coverage, emma

I have two sort of tests in my project. One of them is ending "Test", the other is ending with "IT". 
How can i tell emma that it should take all test classes in account?

Kayser

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but the maven emma plugin [properties](http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/properties.html) link has a reference to the following property:

`maven.emma.filter.includes` Specifies a list of patterns, separated with white space and/or commas. Example: com.foo.*.

You could try specifiying the property with value like `**Test **IT` - either through maven command line (`-Dmaven.emma.filter.includes="**Test **IT"`) or through plugin configuration (though I don't see documentation on the latter).

Comment: Unfortunately, this Emma plugin (http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin) is not the same as this one (http://mojo.codehaus.org/emma-maven-plugin). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531608/which-emma-maven-plugin-should-i-be-using