# Emma coverage with Powermock

Tags: fork, code-coverage, maven-surefire-plugin, emma

We have emma configured in our project which generates the coverage report.  Whole setup was working fine until I introducted PowerMock to mock some of the static methods.

When I annotate a class with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class), emma tries to start coverage process again and throws up addressbind exception.  I think maven surefire is forking a new JVM for different runner and emma tries to startup again on new JVM.

I tried with different options for surefire forkMode, but does not help.

    `Running util.HttpClientFactoryTest
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.154 sec
    Running xxx.util.ServiceConnectorUtilTest
    EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ...
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)`

An idea on how to get around this?  Any help greatly appretiated.  Thanks

Comment: Use [jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). See [run jacoco in test phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531608/which-emma-maven-plugin-should-i-be-using/9533745#9533745)

Comment: I have the same problem, has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/powermock/FKRGTkYGb9s seams to be the same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify the version of the emma plugin in to use maven will default to

```
<groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

If you specify in the build tag the latest version 1.2 (or 1.1)

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
              <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>...
```

the issue should disappear

Comment: this one really helped

Answer (score 0):

Bumping emma plugin version might work for plain java project but the latest android version of com.amazon.emma-droid still doesn't have this fix.

The problem appears only if you use at least two different JunitClassRunners (e.g. default one and @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)). I faced with the same issue when started to use RobolectricTestRunner. The workaround is to use the same JunitClassRunner for every test case in the module. E.g. use @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) even for simple JUnits w/o any PowerMock.